# What's the difference between java.lang.String.getBytes() and java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode()?

Tags: java

I was reading through the source code of [java.lang.String](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html), specifically [getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

```
 public byte[] getBytes(Charset charset) {
         if (charset == null) throw new NullPointerException();
            return StringCoding.encode(charset, value, offset, count);
 }
```

However, I couldn't find the StringCoding.encode() method in the Java API.  I'd like to be able to compare it with [java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20boolean%29), since that class/method is referenced as an alternative in the String.getBytes() javadoc.  How do I find the StringCoding class, and it's source code? And what is the difference between the respective .encode() methods?

Comment: See http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/StringCoding.java.html (It's not a public class...)

Comment: The source for StringCoding comes with String in the JDK.  In your IDE you can use `<ctrl>+<click>` to navigate to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that with a `CharsetEncoder` you can choose how to fail; this is the [`CodingErrorAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html) class.

By default, `String`'s `.getBytes()` uses `REPLACE`. Most uses of `CharsetEncoder` however will `REPORT` insead.

You can see an example of `CodingErrorAction` usage at the end of [this page](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html).

One such example of `REPORT` usage is in java.nio.file. At least on Unix systems, a pathname which you created from a `String` will be encoded before it is written to disks; if the encoding fails (for instance, you use `ö` and system charset US-ASCII), the JDK will refuse to create the file and you will be greeted with an (unchecked!) `InvalidPathException`.

This is unlike `File` which will create who knows what as a file name, and one more reason to ditch it...